# real quadratic fields with 2 ramified primes

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

I have observed that when considering real quadratic fields with class number 1 and 2 having 2 ramified primes, the first ramified prime was (almost always, like 98% of the time) congruent to $3 \bmod 4$ in the case of class number 1 fields and congruent to $1 \bmod 4$ in the case of class number 2 fields. Is there any result known in the litterature regarding these ? Maybe something stated in the language of binary quadratic forms ?

for example : http://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/?hst=List&degree=2&signature=%5B2%2C0%5D&class_number=1&num_ram=2&search_type=List

Thanks !

Comment: please give a link to the tables you are using, also explain what you mean by the "first" prime

Comment: @WillJagy by first ramified prime i mean the smallest one. The data is on my pc, computed using Sagemath.

Comment: Alright. Please show a few  of your examples, in the question body

Comment: @reuns I added the lmfdb page where to retrieve the data, everything is shown there.

Comment: Lmfdb doesn't say what is the condition on $d$. $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is ramified at exactly two primes iff $d=(-1)^k n^2 p$ with $(-1)^kp\equiv 3,-1 \bmod 8$ or $d= (-1)^kn^2 pq$ with $(-1)^kpq\equiv 1,5\bmod 8$ or $d=(-1)^kn^2 2p$ with $p$ odd.

Comment: @reuns where did you find this result ?

Comment: @ThePhoenix Thank you for your answer ! Do you have any good reference on genus theory that discusses these ideas ?

Comment: The reference is : Lemmermeyer, Reciprocity Laws